# Creating a super simple table applet in java

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to create an applet which displays a simple table with no headers or other decoration. Could anyone be so kind as to show me the code for this? All the examples I've found haven't compiled or have included extra features which I don't need. A simple 2 x 2 table with empty cells and no headers is what I'm looking for. Thanks to all in advance...

Code for skaffman:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class danTeamProject extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
char[][] charValues = new char[10][10];
danTable aTable;
boolean allowUserInput = false;

public void init()
{
    Button BtnStart = new Button("Start");
    BtnStart.addActionListener((ActionListener)this);   //cast
    this.add(BtnStart); //add action listener to button


    aTable = new danTable();
    aTable.setVisible(true);


}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    aTable.draw(g);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
{

}

}
```

and

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class danTable extends JPanel
{



public danTable()
{

 // Create with initial data
Object[][] cellData = {
    {"row1-col1", "row1-col2"},
    {"row2-col1", "row2-col2"}};
String[] columnNames = {"col1", "col2"};

JTable table = new JTable(cellData, columnNames);

}
}
```

Comment: We're not writing your work for you. Show us what you've tried so far and we'll advise.

Comment: I didn't want to include my code because it looks so bad and the answer is probably very simple. But if you think it will help...

Comment: @danwoods: Getting used to going through a code review is something you should get used to.  That said, this might help: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html

Comment: Thanks rexem! Followed the first example under "Creating a JTable Component" (the second one is what I really wanted, but it created errors, and right now I just want to create a table) but still can't get the table top be viewable... any ideas as to why I can't see the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the code you posted.

Read it as many times as needed until you understand what it does. See also the coding conventions  ( the brackets and the naming of the variables )

I didn't change too much though, I just make it run.

Pay special attention to the difference between your code and this one ( they are not too much though ) Feel free to ask in case of doubts

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DanTeamProject extends Applet {
    char[][] charValues = new char[10][10];
    DanTable aTable;
    boolean allowUserInput = false;

    public void init()  {
        Button btnStart = new Button("Start");
        this.add(btnStart);
        aTable = new DanTable();
        this.add( aTable );
    }
}

class DanTable extends JPanel {
    public DanTable() {
        Object[][] cellData = {
            {"row1-col1", "row1-col2"},
            {"row2-col1", "row2-col2"}};
        String[] columnNames = {"col1", "col2"};
        add(  new JTable(cellData, columnNames) ) ;
    }
}
```

Here's the HTML used to view it

```
<applet code="DanTeamProject.class" width=100 height=140></applet>
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a JTable and add the table to a JPanel (instead of a JScrollPane) and the header will not appear. Read the JTable API and follow the link to the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tables" for working examples.

Comment: I've read and re-read the "How to use Tables" tutorial, and when I try to compile and execute to code it provides I get lots of errors, which make it hard to comprehend what the tutorial is trying to help me understand

Comment: Would you implement the first part like this?  
JTable table = new JTable(dataModel);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(table);

That produces a new error: 
./danTable.java:23: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor JPanel(javax.swing.JTable)
location: class javax.swing.JPanel
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(table);
                     ^